# Filtrar registros de un día completo

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Estoy intentando filtrar los registros por fecha, sin embargo no estoy seguro que podria faltarme ya que aunque en la url aparece el parametro obtenido este no filtra nada, no muestra ningun item, a continuación comparto mi codigo:

**clients_controller.rb**

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:created_at].present?
      @clients = Client.where(created_at: params[:created_at])
    else
      @clients = Client.all
    end
  end
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag({ controller: :clients, action: :index }, { method: :get } ) do %>
    <%= date_field_tag :created_at %>
  <%= submit_tag "Filtrar", name: nil %>
<% end %>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
      <th>Service</th>
      <th>Note</th>
      <th>Check in</th>
      <th>Delivery</th>
      <th>Delivered</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @clients.each do |client| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= client.name %></td>
        <td><%= client.phone %></td>
        <td><%= client.service.name %></td>
        <td><%= client.note %></td>
        <td><%= client.check_in %></td>
        <td><%= client.delivery %></td>
        <td><%= client.delivered %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', client %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_client_path(client) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', client, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<%= link_to 'New Client', new_client_path %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes consultar a la base de datos los registros creados en un rango de tiempo en vez de en una fecha específica.
Por ejemplo, si tienes como fecha `2019-02-07`, en tu caso realizas la siguiente consulta:

```
date = '2019-02-07'
puts Client.where(created_at: date).to_sql
# SELECT "clients".* FROM "clients" WHERE "clients"."created_at" = '2019-02-07'
```

En cambio si parseas esa fecha que viene en string y la conviertes a un objeto `Date` de ruby, puedes obtener los rangos de inicio/fin de dicho día fácilmente:

```
parsed_date = Date.parse(date) # => Thu, 07 Feb 2019
puts Client.where(created_at: parsed_date.midnight..parsed_date.end_of_day).to_sql
# SELECT "clients".* FROM "clients"
# WHERE ("clients"."created_at" BETWEEN '2019-02-07 00:00:00.000000'
#                               AND '2019-02-07 23:59:59.999999')
```

Comment: Tremendo Alter! Te agradezco muchismo la aclaración me ha venido muy bien! =D